# What is needed to be done to migrate chaincode from v0.6 to v1.0?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I wrote some Hyperledger Fabric chaincode for v0.6 in Golang, and I want to use v0.6 chaincode in v1.0.

How should I migrate the chaincode from v0.6 to v1.0?
What is the difference between v0.6 and v1.0 from chaincode perspective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [article](https://developer.ibm.com/blockchain/wp-content/uploads/sites/87/Migration-of-Auction-issue-0.5.pdf) might help you. It's a document about the migration of the Auction chaincode from v0.6  to v1.0